# Using substr() with Drupal search-result.tpl.php returning fewer characters than expected

Tags: search

In my search-result.tpl.php file I want to return only the first 200 characters of the body field before outputting it to the screen (assuming there are that many characters). I'm trying to use the following code in my search-result.tpl.php file but it's just outputting like the first 32 characters or so...any idea why that might be?

```
<?php
$body = substr(render($teaser['body']), 0, 200);
if (strlen($body) == 200) {
    $body .= "...";
}
?>

<li class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <div class="search-snippet-info">
      <div class="icon"><?php print render($teaser['field_icon']); ?></div>
      <div class="teaser">
      <header>
      <h2><a href="<?php print $result['link']; ?>"><?php print $result['title']; ?></a></h2>
      </header>
      <em><?php print render($teaser['field_type']); ?></em>
      <strong><?php print render($teaser['field_event_dates']); ?></strong>
      <?php // print render($teaser['field_screenshot']); ?>
      <?php print $body; ?>
      </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that kind of process in a tpl, use a preprocess function in your theme's template.php. Also keep in mind that if you output a substring of a rendered body you may break HTML code because not closed or damaged HTML tags (unless body is plain text).

Comment: @tunic. Thanks for the feedback. No HTML code, just text. I'm trying the following with not much luck (in template.php):
$variables['body'] = substr(render($teaser['body']), 0, 200);
  if (strlen($variables['body']) >= 200) {
 $variables['body'] .= "...";
  }
When I then try to print $body in the tpl file it shows exactly as it was before with truncated text at around 15-25 characters only...not 200. Thoughts?